# Feynman Rules in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I am trying to find the feynman rules with FeynCalc Package. K1 and K2 are the mésons $K^+$ and $K^-$

```
    \[Phi]k = ( {   {0, 0, QuantumField[K1]},   {0, 0, 0},   {QuantumField[K2], 0, 0}  } ); D\[Phi]k = ( {   {0, 0, CovariantD[\[Mu]] . QuantumField[K1]},   {0, 0, 0},
   {CovariantD[\[Mu]] . QuantumField[K2], 0, 0}  } );
IntKaons = 
 Simplify[  Expand[1/(12 f^2)Tr[(D\[Phi]k . \[Phi]k - \[Phi]k.D\[Phi]k).(D\[Phi]k.\[Phi]k-\[Phi]k . D\[Phi]k) +M.\[Phi]k . \[Phi]k . \[Phi]k . \[Phi]k]]];

FeynRule[QuantumField[K2]QuantumField[K2]CovariantD[\[Mu]].QuantumField[K1]CovariantD[\[Mu]].QuantumField[K1],{QuantumField[K1][p1],QuantumField[K2][p2],QuantumField[K1][p3],QuantumField[K2][p4]}]
```

How can I put the information that K2 is the antiparticle of K1?